# Why does implicit casting work while reflection casting throws exception?

Tags: java, reflection, casting, autoboxing

Suppose there is the following code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static  <T> T implicitCaster(Class<T> cls, Object o) {
    return (T) o;
}

public static <T> T reflectionCaster(Class<T> cls, Object o) {
    return cls.cast(o);
}
```

The code works as expected in both cases with the following exception, found in primitives:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(implicitCaster(int.class, 42));
    System.out.println(reflectionCaster(int.class, 42));
}
```

The first call works as expected but the second call throws `java.lang.ClassCastException`.

Is this a corner case in which autoboxing was disregarded? Or is it impossible to provide autoboxing in this case, of reflection casting? 
Or is there something else causing this inconsistency?

Edit: calling this code works as expected:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(implicitCaster(Integer.class, 42));
    System.out.println(reflectionCaster(Integer.class, 42));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because of type erasure.

At runtime, generic type parameters don't exist.
Casting an object to a generic type parameter has no effect.  (which is why you get the unchecked cast warning)

Therefore, your first line autoboxes `42` to `Object` to pass to the method.
The function then returns that `Object`, which is passed to `System.out.println`.

---

Your second call calls the `cast` method of the `int` primitive type.
This throws an exception, because objects cannot be casted to primitive types.  (auto-boxing is a purely compile-time feature, so it doesn't help)

The error happens when `cast()` [checks `isInstance()`](http://www.grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/Class.java#Class.cast%28java.lang.Object%29) to verify that the cast is valid.

The docs for [`isInstance()` say](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance%28java.lang.Object%29):

> Specifically, if this Class object represents a declared class, this method returns true if the specified Object argument is an instance of the represented class (or of any of its subclasses); it returns false otherwise. If this Class object represents an array class, this method returns true if the specified Object argument can be converted to an object of the array class by an identity conversion or by a widening reference conversion; it returns false otherwise. If this Class object represents an interface, this method returns true if the class or any superclass of the specified Object argument implements this interface; it returns false otherwise. **If this Class object represents a primitive type, this method returns false.**

(emphasis added)

---

Your edit works because you are no longer using a primitive type.
In both cases, the compiler autoboxes `42` so that it can be passed as an object.

The first call, as before, has no effect.
The second call verifies that the boxed integer is in fact an instance of the `Integer` class, then returns it.

Comment: I have written there that the code works for every given class with the exception of primitives; so casting an object to a generic type is possible. Secondly you can cast objects to primitives.

Comment: @m3th0dman: I didn't say it's impossible.  I said it has no effect at runtime.

Comment: I understand now; but doesn't this kind of break the contract of the cast method? Technically the cast is possible.

Comment: @m3th0dman: That depends on how you define "cast".  See this (C#) blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/19/representation-and-identity.aspx.  Basically, as far the the runtime is concerned, primitives aren't objects and cannot be cast.

Comment: @m3th0dman: In Java in particular, such a cast would be meaningless, since it would still return `Integer` rather than `int`.

Comment: @m3th0dman:  IMO, it fails because `Integer` to `int` actually requires (auto) unboxing and casting only happens either between primitives or between reference types. `(Integer) 42` or `(int) new Integer(42)` should not be considered as casting, I think. +1 to the answer.